# Eclipse + Equinox -> Cannot find the EventAdmin classes

Tags: java, eclipse, osgi, osgi-bundle, equinox

currently working on OSGI bundles with Equinox in Eclipse and want to use an EventAdmin like shown in this tutorial: https://nickolaylaptev.wordpress.com/2015/11/26/equinox-eventadmin-why-not/

However, no matter what I do, Eclipse doesn't seem to find all the required classes like for example EventConstants and EventHandler.
It doesn't find any path to import them.
I've already downloaded the packages from here: http://download.eclipse.org/equinox/ and the actual JDK is installed as well.

What do I still have to do to enable the Eventadmin?
Any idea?

Huge thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you talking about compile time, or runtime? What's the error message?

Comment: It was both. At compile time, the classes were just underlined in red, saying for example "EventConstants cannot be resolved". However, uhm.. today, it just solved itself for some reason o.O Maybe it was the PC restart though I had restarted Eclipse itself multiple times before too... Anyways, thank you for your comment nevertheless!